# Taxonomy for custom post type not found

Tags: categories, taxonomy, 404-error, dropdown

I'm trying to use taxonomies to create categories for my custom post type.
I registered the necessary components:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'bkroadkill',
        array(
                'labels'        => array(
                'name'          => __( 'Roadkills' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Roadkill' )
            ),
        'public'      => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports'    => array( 'title', 'custom-fields', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments' )
        )
    );
}

function roadkill_categories_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Roadkill Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Roadkill Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Roadkill Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Roadkill Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Roadkill Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Roadkill Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Roadkill Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Roadkill Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Roadkill Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Roadkill Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Roadkill Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'name'  => 'roadkill_category',
        'id'  => 'roadkill_category',
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'roadkill_category', 'bkroadkill', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'roadkill_categories_init' );
```

And I was able to create some roadkill categories in the wp-admin backend. But as I click on view it will result in a not found page.

Also I am not able to fetch my categories to use them in my dropdown of my form (it will be empty).

```
        <?php $args = array(
                'name'               => 'roadkill_category',
                'taxonomy'           => 'roadkill_category',
                'hide_if_empty'      => false,
            ); ?>

            <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

What did I miss here?

EDIT:

There are two different not found pages:

1. when permalink is not working (404)
2. when content is not found I guess. The title is set correctly then.

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks since registering the CPT and CT?

Comment: I went to settings-> permalinks and saved several times yeah. I'm playing around with all the parameters for hours now..

Comment: Can you assign a `roadkill_category` to your custom post type? Does the post-count in the admin increase? Does it work then?

Comment: Yes when I do that in the backend it is working fine. I wouldn't even need the links of the category to be working, but I need the dropdown in my custom form. I tried different ways there (wp_dropdown_categories or fetching data with get_terms itself) but I won't get any results

Comment: Okay now I have the category in my dropdown for which I created a post. So my dropdown shows just categories where entries already exist. I guess I will figure it out

Comment: I just used `hide_if_empty`instead of `hide_empty` ...

Comment: I'm struggling with fetching the data to display it now. I'm using `wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID, 'roadkill_category');` and echo `$term->name` in a foreach loop. But no data is displayed although I can see the connections are made correctly